# AWS CLI Create Folder and Upload PNG Files Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm trying to upload a folder to AWS S3 containing 2,000 PNG files via the CLI. The folder "folder" does not exist, so I am also trying to create it from this code. I haven't used it before, so i'm sure my issue is an easy fix. When I try to run the below code from the CLI...

```
aws s3 cp /Users/charlie/Desktop/Chemical-Images-CAS/chemical_image_50-00-0.png s3://research-homepage/folder
```

...I get the following error

```
upload failed: Desktop/Chemical-Images-CAS/chemical_image_50-00-0.png to s3://research-homepage/chemical_image_50-00-0.png An error occurred (SignatureDoesNotMatch) when calling the PutObject operation: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
```

Is this because my sign in is off, or am I missing something? Shouldn't this upload that single PNG to S3?

Also, when I go to upload all the images, would I be fine to simply remove "chemical_image_50-00-0.png" to give it the folder path?

Comment: When uploading to S3, indicate the full key of the target object e.g. `s3://research-homepage/folder/chemical_image_50-00-0.png`. On the signing issue, check that the AWS credentials you are supplying (presumably in the default profile in `~/.aws/credentials`) are correct.

Comment: The error is complaining about your AWS credentials. If you run `aws s3 ls`, does it return a list of buckets? I suspect that you are using invalid credentials.

Comment: Thank you both, it turned out it was the secret key bugging out :(